# Visual Studio 2013 developers license javascript error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, google-chrome, licensing, windows-store

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 installed, and I would like to start coding windows store apps. Every time I create a project, I'm getting the notification that I need a developer license. This is fine to me, so I press the 'I agree' button.

After doing this, Visual Studio seems to be trying to make some connection to the web, and the next thing happening is a JavaScript error. Literally translated from Dutch it says:

> You need JavaScript to login to your Microsoft-account. This browser doesn't support JavaScript or scripts are being blocked. Look into the online Help of your browser to see if the browser supports JavaScript or to enable scripts.

My default browser is Google Chrome, and in the settings of Google Chrome, JavaScript is enabled by default. How do I solve all of this? I really want to start creating windows store apps.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this.

The problem is: Microsoft Visual Studio is still making use of Internet Explorer in stead of your chosen default browser. Visual Studio needs to be able to do something with Cookies in Internet Explorer, and this is blocked by default. Lower your security settings on Internet Explorer, and everything is solved.