# Unable to renew Windows 8.1 developer license: script error

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Not sure if this should be asked on stackoverflow, but I'll give it a try. I am unable to continue developing my Windows Store Application project because my developer license was expired, so I tried several times to renew my developer license and every time I get this:
[image: Developer License script error]

When I press "Yes", "Script Error" window disappears and page just keeps being blank. I tried to copy script contents from provided [url](https://auth.gfx.ms/16.000.26706.00/DefaultLogin_PCore.js) and validate it and validator says it has a lot or errors.. Anyway, I don't believe it is javascript error, I believe problem is on my side and I have to update javascript or something else... Maybe someone already faced same issue?

I already tried lowering my security settings as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583639/visual-studio-2013-developers-license-javascript-error), didn't helped.

Visual Studio 2013 Express

Windows 8.1 Pro x64

Comment: The problem is not relative to a specific version of visual studio, I am running the same issue trying to renew the license on a tablet without VisualStudio...

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I've submitted my issue to microsoft team, you can track progress using this link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3110892/unable-to-renew-developer-license

Comment: Having the same problem here (Sweden). Trying renew a license for building a Xamarin project in VS2013, will follow the issue.

Answer (score 2):

We're sitting in Germany, too. But I don't think it's a local issue, as we all access the same script.

@Martin: If you don't need the visual Win8 part you can use Windows 10. Just tested it on my personal machine running Win10 and VS 2015. There it works.

Answer (score 1):

It has been fixed now, it is working fine, i just tried.

Answer (score 0):

It works now with Visual Studio 2013 Update 5!